# How could I edit a recipe object inside an array of recipe objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a recipe box project using React, and to edit the existing recipe, I tried this code, `this.state.recipe` is currently an array of recipe objects:

```
editRecipe = (recipe) => {
  this.state.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name).name = recipe.name;
  this.state.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name).ingredients = recipe.ingredients;
}
```

And pass this method to the `<EditRecipe edit={this.editRecipe} />` as a prop.
However, when I activate the method in that component than invoke the edit prop, there is an error message that says : "this.state.recipe.find(...) is undefined"

Is there any other approach to edit the recipe?

Here is the error message that I got [image]

Thank you.

Comment: As per the error, its look like `this.state.recipe` is not an array. Can you please share the value that you are getting in `this.state.recipe` inside `editRecipe` callback.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should have the `this` avalable for the EditRecipe component, so change the way you pass the function as props

```
<EditRecipe edit={this.editRecipe.bind(this)} />
```

Also you should change the function as,

```
editRecipe = function(recipe){
  let selectedObj;
  selectedObj = this.state.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name)
  if(selectedObj){
    selectedObj.name = recipe.name;
    selectedObj.ingredients =recipe.ingredients;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it still gives the error message `this.state.recipe.find(...) is undefined`

Comment: Added fix for this.state.recipe.find(...) is undefined

Comment: Thank you, it works but not until I click on the "Edit Recipe" button the second time that the recipe got updated.

Comment: Please add the code of onclick, without i cant comment on that part. And if the question is answered please mark this answered for the stack over flow community

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function does not have its own `this`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Not sure but you can try regular function instead:

```
editRecipe = function(recipe){
  this.state.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name).name = recipe.name;
  this.state.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name).ingredients = 
  recipe.ingredients;
}
```

Comment: @lambchopp, could you log what is in `this.state.recipe`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find` and `Object assign` to `edit/update` an item inside of an array.

I did an example with explanation of comments beside the code

```js
const JSON = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
  },

]

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: JSON,
    };
  }
  
edit = () =>{
  const newData = {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "New@email.com",//changing email address
  }
this.setState(prevState=>{
  const findItem = prevState.data.find(row => row.username === 'Samantha'); // find the item that you want to edit/update it
  return Object.assign(findItem, newData) //update the data
})

}
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.data.map(row=>
        <li key={row.id}>{row.name} : {row.email}</li>
        )}
        <button onClick={this.edit}>Edit Clementine Bauch Email</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

In your code, after you find the item you need to set `recipe` state with a new data using Object assign.

```
editRecipe = (recipe) => {
  this.setState(prevState=>{
  const findItem = prevState.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name);
    const findItem2 = prevState.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name);
    return Object.assign(findItem && findItem2, recipe)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the error message is `prevState.recipe.find(...) is undefined`. I don't know why since my recipe state is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code so I will break down one by one.

- `this.state is undefined`: I think you already fix by binding so it's ok.
- `this.state.recipe.find() is undefined`: you acclaimed that recipe is an array of objects. First, you should check again where your `recipe` data comes from, and whether it's initialised as array or not. Second, check your browser. `Array.find` [is not supported by Internet Explore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) so change your testing browser or use alternative solution for `Array.find` is necessary.
- `this.state.recipe.find(obj => obj.name === recipe.name).name = recipe.name;` is unsafe since you assume you can always find a recipe object in the list. In case Array.find does not find anything, you might receive error `cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

Comment: Do you suggest another approach?

Comment: Your question provides too little detail of the component holding the state to answer accurately. The original approach is not totally wrong, btw; but you need to be aware of possible cases that I pointed out to avoid errors.

Comment: Yeah the find method assumes that I don't change the original recipe's name. If I change the name, what should I do in order to still make the edit possible?